# How to get element using javaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to get value of input element using javaScript.
I am new to all this Please help me.

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
var stringVal = document.getElementById('youInputID').value;
```

Answer (score 3):

Other users have answered the question above already.  I would also like to recommend looking at one of the javascript libraries. They make this kind of work much easier. My current favorite is [jquery](http://jquery.com/).  It is amazingly powerful - every day I find some new feature or trick that makes javascript programming easier.

To solve this in jquery you can use:

The line below will create an alert box for the value of an input tag with the id of email using jquery:

```
alert($("#email").val());
```

Here is a complete example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        alert($("#email").val());
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="POST" action="go.php" id="login_form">
      <input type="text" class="inputtext" title="Email" id="email" name="email" value="your@emailaddress" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 Using jQuery straight away will definitely save frustration with all the low level plumbing code. I believe that getting the value from the input element is just one of the many problems that the asker have.

Answer (score 2):

Your Javascript should look similar to this:

```
var elm = document.getElementById('myElement');
var value = elm.value;
```

And your HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="myElement" value="My Value" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" id="testid" value="" />
```

Now you can get the value of above text box like this:

```
document.getElementById('testid').value;
```

Other way:

```
document.form_name_here.element_name.value;
```

Simply run an alert to check if value comes:

```
alert(document.getElementById('testid').value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var txt = document.getElementById('ID-OF-FIELD');
var value = txt.value;
```